# Operations on physical quantities

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis

I know what quantities like meter and second are, they are a certain quantity of one-dimensional space and a certain duration of time respectively. And I know what a measurement of a quantity using a unit is, it's a real number that indicate how many times the unity fits in the quantity. And I know algebraic operations on real numbers. But I don't understand what the result of any algebraic operation on quantities is. Like, I have no idea what a meter divided by a second or a second multiplied by a second are. Could someone explain? Thanks.

Comment: By "one meter divided by one second" we usually mean that something has gone the distance of one meter, while one second of time has elapsed. But we may also mean that something "would have gone the distance of a meter in one second if nothing had changed". Algebraic operations on units are not sufficient to differentiate between the case of constant and instantaneous velocity. That's why we use different notation for finite differences and differentials. $\Delta{x}/\Delta{t}$ is not the same thing as $dx/dt$, even though both have units of $m/s$.

Answer (score 1):

The first two examples of units you gave (meter and second) are *base units*.  They are called that because they are some of the most basic of all units, and are actually defined according to a standard.  For example, the second is defined by the amount of time that a certain number of processes occur within a Cesium atom (this is the cliffnotes version) and a meter is defined by the distance that light travels within a certain (very small) fraction of a second.  There are exactly 7 base units within the Systeme Internationale (SI) system of units, which is one of the most common systems of units within the physical sciences.  Alongside meter and second, the other 5 base units within the SI system are Kilogram (unit of mass), Ampere (unit of electric current), Kelvin (unit of temperature), the Candela (unit of luminous intensity), and the mole (amount of a substance).  These 7 units were defined by the scientific community to be what they are. Now here's where the real answer to your question comes into play, because *all other units* aside from the 7 I just mentioned are derived units.

A derived unit is basically just some combination of the 7 units listed above.  For example, a meter per second ($m/s$) is a unit for either speed or velocity.  It is a derived unit consisting of the base unit for distance (meter) and the base unit for time (second).  Derived units are formed by just algebraically combining the base units, and you follow the same operations that you would use to find whatever quantity the unit represents. So, to return to the velocity example, the equation definition of velocity is $$v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$$ where $\Delta x$ is the change in an object's displacement and $\Delta t$ is some interval of time.  Well, displacement is a special way of measuring distance, so it carries a unit of $m$, and time intervals are commonly measured in seconds ($s$).  So the unit of the numerator is meters, and the unit of the denominator is seconds.  When you divide a meter by a second, you get a derived unit of $m/s$ which is read as "meter per second".  Note that all units can algebraically combine this way.  The unit for force, which is called a Newton ($N$) as a shortcut, is really a kilogram-meter per second squared ($kgm/s^2$). That's because a net force is a mass (unit of $kg$) multiplied by an acceleration (unit of $m/s^2$).